# Cannot find symbol enum

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am manually compiling Java code with javac and I am getting the following errors:

```
Packet.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    public final PacketType type;
                 ^
  symbol:   class PacketType
  location: class Packet
Packet.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
            type = PacketType.UNDEF;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable PacketType
  location: class Packet
Packet.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        type = PacketType.values()[message[0]];
               ^
  symbol:   variable PacketType
  location: class Packet
3 errors
```

Packet.java:

```
  package gameManager.gameServer;

  import java.util.logging.Logger;

  public class Packet {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Class.class.getSimpleName());

    public static final int PACKET_SIZE = 1024; //Packet size in bytes



    public final PacketType type;
    public final byte[] data = new byte[PACKET_SIZE-1]; //Data size is PacketSize minus PacketType Header




    public Packet(byte[] message) {
        if(message.length != PACKET_SIZE) {
            LOGGER.warning("Tried to create a packet with insufficent amount of data");
            type = PacketType.UNDEF;
            return;
        }

        type = PacketType.values()[message[0]];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = message[i+1];
        }
    }




  }
```

PacketType.java:

```
package gameManager.gameServer;

public enum PacketType {

    UNDEF, JOIN_SERVER, MOVE, SHOOT, CHANGE_INVENTORY;

}
```

I am compiling by using
`javac PacketType.java && javac Packet.java`

I don't know why this won't compile, I have already compiled PacketType.java and Eclipse has no issues seeing PacketType from Packet

Comment: We have neither your code, nor the command you are using to compile. This makes it hard to know what you're doing wrong, and correspondingly hard to help.

Comment: Please show an [mcve] so it's clear what the problem is.

Comment: seems like you're missing an `import` directive for `PacketType.`

Comment: Ensure that you have file PacketType.class in your --class-path or PacketType.java in your --source-path

Comment: But PacketType and Packet are in the same package. I thought you don't have to have an import directive for classes in the same package?

Comment: I ran `javac -sourcepath PacketType.java Packet.java` and it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change directory to *src*, try the command:

```
javac -cp src ./src/gameManager/gameServer/Packet.java
```

Comment: Tried it, got `file not found: ./src/gameManager/gameServer/Packet.java` so I tried `./gameManager/gameServer/Packet.java` and got the same error

Comment: you use Eclipse right? u will have folder structure like this:
 {PROJECT_HOME}/src/gameManager/gameServer/Packet.java
 {PROJECT_HOME}/src/gameManager/gameServer/PacketType.java
at  {PROJECT_HOME}, run the command above

Comment: Yep, that worked. Sorry, I thought I needed to be in the src file, not the {PROJECT_HOME} file